# Textbox RTL mixed with LTR markup

Tags: html, css, right-to-left

http://jsfiddle.net/T7gUX/10/

`<input type=text dir=ltr value="Why {$subject}?">`

`<input type=text dir=rtl value="למה {$subject}?">`

I am trying to write a translation tool for my project.  RTL language is part of the requirement, and so is markdown (LTR) inside the text.  The problem is that either the markdown renders consistently or the RTL text does, but never both.

How do I make the textbox readable while editing RTL text with mixed LTR markdown?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? Are you using resources? (resx files)

Comment: You mean - within one element?

Comment: yes, within a single element.

The problem is the markup looks VERY strange in the context of the edit box (for instance the $ goes to the right instead of the left of the keyword).